# sending a pointer of global variable's member to WinHttpQueryHeaders (WinHTTP API) does not change it's value

Tags: c++11, winhttp

I have the following code snippet:

```
        // Using HttpQueryInfo to obtain the size of the buffer into dwSize.
        if (!WinHttpQueryHeaders(hRequest,
            WINHTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF,
            WINHTTP_HEADER_NAME_BY_INDEX, NULL, &st.dwSize, WINHTTP_NO_HEADER_INDEX))
        {
            // An ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER is expected because you
            // are looking for the size of the headers.  If any other
            // error is encountered, display error information.
            DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
            if (dwErr != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
            {
                DEBUG_PRINT(("Error %d encountered.", dwErr));
                return;
            } else {
                // enters here and prints '0' (initial value)
                DEBUG_PRINT(("size of buffer: ", &st.dwSize));
            }
        }
```

while `st` is a global object with a member `dwSize`.

When I'm running this part in debugging mode I see that `st.dwSize` does not change its value after the call to `WinHttpQueryHeaders`.

But if I create a local var `DWORD dwSize = 0` and send `&dwSize` to `WinHttpQueryHeaders`, it does obtain buffer size and succeeds to change its value.

is there any reason why I shouldn't send a pointer of a global object's member to `WinHttpQueryHeaders` or to any other external API functions?

Comment: You should avoid global objects in general, because they are problematic from the software design perspective, but there's nothing wrong with them on the Winapi or C++ level. There must be some other factor in play there, but we can only guess what it could be. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason `WinHttpQueryHeaders` did not succeed to change `st.dwSize` it's because I declered `st` as a `static` global var.

```
static WinHttpSubtransport st;
```

and as written in [Scope rules of the "persistent" variables in C](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/%7Echeung/Courses/255/Syllabus/1-C-intro/scope-global.html):

> A static global variable is a global variable that can only be accessed by functions in the same C program file as the variable.